# How to solve feign client getting 302 response from eureka server?

Tags: spring-boot, netflix-eureka, feign

I have eureka server ."Main core service" is always registered with eureka server.
currently I am trying to create rest client using feign in "sub service" to connect with main core server through eureka server.

But, I am always get 302 response from eureka server. So, I created sample main, sub, eureka server. But, it is working fine as sub service can get rest response successfully

I dont know what i am doing wrong

1. feign client

@FeignClient(name = "TACITUSTEST")

```
public interface TacitusRecorderConnector {
    @GetMapping(path = "/configurations/rtspserver")
    public TacitusRecorderConfiguration getRtspServerConfiguration();
}
```

2. In this line, i am getting following exception

   ```
   TacitusRecorderConfiguration configuration = tacitusRecorderConnector.getRtspServerConfiguration();
   ```

**Exception:**

```
feign.FeignException: [302] during [GET] to [http://TACITUSTEST/configurations/rtspserver] [TacitusRecorderConnector#getRtspServerConfiguration()]: []
        at feign.FeignException.errorStatus(FeignException.java:199)
        at feign.FeignException.errorStatus(FeignException.java:185)
        at feign.codec.ErrorDecoder$Default.decode(ErrorDecoder.java:92)
        at feign.AsyncResponseHandler.handleResponse(AsyncResponseHandler.java:96)
        at feign.SynchronousMethodHandler.executeAndDecode(SynchronousMethodHandler.java:138)
        at feign.SynchronousMethodHandler.invoke(SynchronousMethodHandler.java:89)
        at feign.ReflectiveFeign$FeignInvocationHandler.invoke(ReflectiveFeign.java:100)
        at jdk.proxy2/jdk.proxy2.$Proxy91.getRtspServerConfiguration(Unknown Source)
        at de.vc.launcher.controller.RecorderConfigurationInitializer.run(RecorderConfigurationInitializer.java:36)
        at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.callRunner(SpringApplication.java:771)
        at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.callRunners(SpringApplication.java:755)
        at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:315)
        at de.vc.launcher.LauncherApp.main(LauncherApp.java:20)
```

Please help me out thanks